# How do i input automatic values(nothing) in windows bat script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\bala\Desktop\WORK\Projects\CERTIFICATE\check\cacerts2"  > ans.txt
```

The above code in bat file will ask for prompt like "Enter password" and I have to input nothing that i will just press enter to get the desired result.

How do I automatically insert that value(pressing enter in the command prompt) in the bat script itself? Please advise

Comment: See whether `(echo;) | keytool -list etc...`  Or try `keytool -list etc... <NUL`.

Comment: Thanks rojo :) i got to give printf '\n' | mycommand here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your time.
I got it. I have to give like below code line
    printf '\n' | keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\bala\Desktop\WORK\Projects\CERTIFICATE\check\cacerts2"  > ans.txt